# Does a wall need to be finished with drywall where an outlet receptacle is located?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have framed out a wall that is going to be completely covered by a custom media center cabinet. I will have a plastic outlet box there nailed to one of the studs located behind  where the TV would go. The cabinets will screw into the framing studs. My question is, do I even need to drywall this before I put my cabinets in? It will be completely covered by the cabinets MDF backing so I feel like I don't really need to drywall it. The only thing I can think of that might not be code compliant is the outlet receptacle. Anyone know if it is a hazard or against code to not have drywall there? Do i need special wires or box for this type of application?

Comment: Not sure, but I think there are fire code/advice that walls be covered with fire resistant materials like drywall in living spaces.

Comment: I take it the receptacle's box will protrude thru the MDF, or is there just going to be a cutout against this? Also, what's on the other side of the wall? Another room of yours? The great outdoors? Your garage?  Somebody else's living space?

Comment: Any reason not to drywall the wall, like it is odd size and you end up wasting a lot?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sitting in my basement right now. Plenty of receptacles. *No drywall*. All receptacle boxes (and switch boxes and light fixture boxes) are mounted to studs or joists or cinderblock. As long as everything is secure and covered properly (metal boxes definitely work best in this type of room, even if you're not using metal conduit) this is perfectly fine.

There are some situations where you need drywall (or certain other wall surfaces) for fire safety - e.g., the wall between a garage and a house. In such situations, any holes in the wall (to run wires or for the receptacle boxes) need to be sealed properly. It does not sound like any such rules would apply in your situation of an interior wall.

The other thing to keep in mind is that junction boxes (whether they contain receptacles or are simply used to join two sections of wire) must remain accessible. A piece of furniture placed in front of a receptacle is fine. A piece of furniture screwed into the wall so that it blocks the receptacle is **not** OK.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not require gypsum board (or any other covering) on walls, except 1) on the garage side of the wall between the house and garage, 2) water resistant wall covering in a shower or around a tub, 3) fire or sound wall between two living units (condos), 4) fire wall due to wall too close to property line.

If you do provide a wall covering, it must meet the size, thickness, mounting requirements, etc. as specified in the code. (See ICC R Chapter 7).

So, you could provide peanut butter on the walls, if you want.